# An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details

Tags: magento-2.1.2

I install magento 2.1.2 on localhost. Try to open it then it gives this error.

> An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details.

If i use developer mode to see the message.
(To Use Developer Mode : In .htaccess file i Comment out "SetEnv MAGE_MODE developer")

Then It shows This message

> exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'magento2'' in G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php:129 Stack trace: #0 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(129): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'root', '', Array) #1 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(111): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect() #2 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(347): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect() #3 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(861): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_connect() #4 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(931): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->quote('default', NULL) #5 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(1372): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->quoteInto('{{fieldName}} =...', 'default', NULL, NULL) #6 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(2830): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->quoteInto('{{fieldName}} =...', 'default') #7 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(2814): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_prepareQuotedSqlCondition('{{fieldName}} =...', 'default', '`scope`') #8 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb.php(477): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->prepareSqlCondition('`scope`', 'default') #9 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb.php(408): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->_getConditionSql('`scope`', 'default') #10 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb.php(390): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->_translateCondition('scope', 'default') #11 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\module-store\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Collection\Scoped.php(59): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->addFieldToFilter('scope', 'default') #12 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection.php(124): Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Collection\Scoped->_initSelect() #13 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\module-store\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Collection\Scoped.php(48): Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactory), Object(Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog), Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategy\Query), Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy), NULL, Object(Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Data)) #14 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(93): Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Collection\Scoped->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactory), Object(Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog), Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategy\Query), Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy), Object(Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Data), 'default', NULL, NULL) #15 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(89): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\Store\M...', Array) #16 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Store\M...', Array) #17 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\var\generation\Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Collection\ScopedFactory.php(43): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('\Magento\Store\...', Array) #18 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\module-store\Model\Config\Reader\DefaultReader.php(63): Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Collection\ScopedFactory->create(Array) #19 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Config\ScopePool.php(112): Magento\Store\Model\Config\Reader\DefaultReader->read() #20 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Config.php(45): Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopePool->getScope('default', NULL) #21 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Config.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Config->getValue('web/secure/use_...', 'default', NULL) #22 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\module-store\Model\HeaderProvider\Hsts.php(48): Magento\Framework\App\Config->isSetFlag('web/secure/use_...') #23 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Response\HeaderManager.php(41): Magento\Store\Model\HeaderProvider\Hsts->canApply() #24 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(123): Magento\Framework\App\Response\HeaderManager->beforeSendResponse(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor)) #25 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\var\generation\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor.php(117): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins('sendResponse', Array, Array) #26 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(185): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->sendResponse() #27 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(156): Magento\Framework\App\Http->handleDeveloperMode(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception)) #28 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(263): Magento\Framework\App\Http->catchException(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception)) #29 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http)) #30 {main} Next exception 'Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'magento2'' in G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php:144 Stack trace: #0 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(111): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect() #1 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(347): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect() #2 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(861): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_connect() #3 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(931): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->quote('default', NULL) #4 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(1372): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->quoteInto('{{fieldName}} =...', 'default', NULL, NULL) #5 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(2830): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->quoteInto('{{fieldName}} =...', 'default') #6 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(2814): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->_prepareQuotedSqlCondition('{{fieldName}} =...', 'default', '`scope`') #7 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb.php(477): Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->prepareSqlCondition('`scope`', 'default') #8 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb.php(408): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->_getConditionSql('`scope`', 'default') #9 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb.php(390): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->_translateCondition('scope', 'default') #10 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\module-store\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Collection\Scoped.php(59): Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb->addFieldToFilter('scope', 'default') #11 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection.php(124): Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Collection\Scoped->_initSelect() #12 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\module-store\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Collection\Scoped.php(48): Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactory), Object(Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog), Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategy\Query), Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy), NULL, Object(Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Data)) #13 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory.php(93): Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Collection\Scoped->__construct(Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactory), Object(Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog), Object(Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategy\Query), Object(Magento\Framework\Event\Manager\Proxy), Object(Magento\Config\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Data), 'default', NULL, NULL) #14 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer.php(89): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\Store\M...', Array) #15 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager.php(57): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create('Magento\Store\M...', Array) #16 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\var\generation\Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Collection\ScopedFactory.php(43): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create('\Magento\Store\...', Array) #17 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\module-store\Model\Config\Reader\DefaultReader.php(63): Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Config\Collection\ScopedFactory->create(Array) #18 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Config\ScopePool.php(112): Magento\Store\Model\Config\Reader\DefaultReader->read() #19 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Config.php(45): Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopePool->getScope('default', NULL) #20 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Config.php(58): Magento\Framework\App\Config->getValue('web/secure/use_...', 'default', NULL) #21 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\module-store\Model\HeaderProvider\Hsts.php(48): Magento\Framework\App\Config->isSetFlag('web/secure/use_...') #22 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Response\HeaderManager.php(41): Magento\Store\Model\HeaderProvider\Hsts->canApply() #23 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(123): Magento\Framework\App\Response\HeaderManager->beforeSendResponse(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor)) #24 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\var\generation\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor.php(117): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->___callPlugins('sendResponse', Array, Array) #25 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(185): Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor->sendResponse() #26 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Http.php(156): Magento\Framework\App\Http->handleDeveloperMode(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception)) #27 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\framework\App\Bootstrap.php(263): Magento\Framework\App\Http->catchException(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap), Object(Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception)) #28 G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http)) #29 {main}

What is the Solution For this Problem .. Can anyone guide me .

Comment: to fix: > try to complete re-boot system and try again. An error has happened during application run. See exception log for details. Could not write error message to log. Please use **developer** mode to see the message. on magento 2.3.0

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/151078)

Answer (score 4):

Pdo is php component to connect mysql

```
Unknown database 'magento2'' in G:\Xxamp\htdocs\magento2.1.2\vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php:129 Stack trace: #0
```

It's seems like mysql connection error. Check your configuration under /app/etc/env.php

In this file, a number of key things are set, including the database connection information:

```
‘host’ => ‘localhost’,
‘dbname’ => ‘magento2database’,
‘username’ => ‘some-sample-username’,
‘password’ => ‘Extremely-Complicated-Password-12345’,
‘model’ => ‘mysql4’,
‘engine’ => ‘innodb’,
‘initStatements’ => ‘SET NAMES utf8;’,
‘active’ => ‘1’,
```

This should help.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else sees this frustrating message.

The fix I found was to uninstall Magento from the directory, then reinstall, but on reinstall, the setup wizard informed me that 2 PHP extensions were missing.

I logged into WHM and use Easy Apache to add those extensions, I put the original files back and voila back in business. Its weird that the logs does not mention those extensions.

Here were the missing PHP Extensions:

PHP Extension Intl. PHP Extension Iconv.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because there may be `setup:install` process running (in background).

You can kill this process and reinstall Magento by using `setup:unistall` and `setup:install`.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue. I just once stopped MySql service and restarted it MySql service from xampp control panel. It resolved the issue in my case.